# Jquery addClass to wp_nav_menu is very slow

Tags: jquery, wordpress, addclass, navigationbar

I have added a li class to my wp_nav_menu with the following simple code

```
$('#menu-navigasjon').children('li').addClass('liparent');
```

When you visit my site http://annalidesign.com, Wordpress will first generate the original navigation menu (vertical) without liparent class, and a split millisecond after that the Jquery code will run and add on the "liparent" class making it horizontal as I want.

The problem is that I can see how the navigation looks a split second before the new liparent class is added. Is there anything I can do to avoid this happening? I've tried to paste the Jquery script right after the HTML for the navbar, but the original vertical navigation bar still shows a split millisecond before.

I've tried using walker function, using the following code without any luck, because I don't know how to ADD classes to the existing li element that Wordpress generates. My code removes all the li classes Wordpress generates and only adds one class. That is not what I want.

```
  class MyWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

   function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
     $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
     $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
   }

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {

       if($depth == 0) {
          $class_names = ' class="liparent"';
       }

       $output .= $indent . '<li' . $class_names . '>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to rewrite the existing walker from scratch or find where the original walker is located and modify that (if you're using a theme)

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the menu initially then use jQuery to show it once the addClass function has run. Here's a stripped-down test case that uses setTimeout to simulate a page loading before jQuery runs Codepen: http://codepen.io/SteveClason/pen/eZqBrw):

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
  <div class="ulwrap">
    <p>This one doesn't blink.</p>
    <ul id="menu-navigasjon">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
    <p>But this one does.</p>
    <ul id="menu-navigasjon2">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.liparent {
  color: red;
}
#menu-navigasjon {
  display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
// This menu is initially hidden by CSS.
$('#menu-navigasjon').children('li').addClass('liparent');
$( '#menu-navigasjon' ).css( 'display', 'block');

// This menu initially displays then is altered by JavaScript. There's a timer to simulate a page loading.
function blink() {
  $('#menu-navigasjon2').children('li').addClass('liparent');
}
setTimeout( blink, 1000 );
```

Comment: I tried it. Added CSS in head, before the jQuery. But it just hides the navigation..

Comment: I've also tried to first hide the navigation, then add the class and then show it. `$('#menu-navigasjon').hide();

$('#menu-navigasjon').children('li').addClass('liparent');

$('#menu-navigasjon').show();` without any luck.

Comment: The second solution in your comments would have the same blink, because first the page would load with the unaltered `#menu-navigasjon` then after the page was loaded jQuery would hide it, add the class,  then show it -- essentially the same thing you have now. But I don't get why hiding the nav with css then revealing it with JS after the addClass doesn't work. I don't see the issue on the url above -- did you get it fixed?